# Gitlab Is there any way to create a fork by commando and recognize it as such?

Tags: command, gitlab, fork

Is there any way to create a fork in gitlab and to be recognized as such without pressing the "fork" button? I can not find the form, that is I create a fork manually by command but then I can not make a merge request to the original project

Comment: Is using the curl command tool an option?

Comment: no, i´m trying to make a class to use with differents "git"